# Delegate a function to all other interfaces

Tags: kotlin, delegates

I have an interface:

```
interface EmployeeActions

interface SalesEmployeeActions : EmployeeActions {
   fun onSaleRequest()
   //..more functions
}

interface HREmployeeActions : EmployeeActions {

} 

...//more EmployeeActions
```

Now the way I am using this in the class is basically an aggregation where I will have many of these objects and I want to call stuff on them all together.

```
class FakeEmployeeDb {
   val employees: MutableList<EmployeeActions> = mutableListOf()

   private val salesEmployees:
     get() = employees.filterIsInstance<SalesEmployeeActions>()

   ....

   val salesManager = object: SalesEmployeeAction {
       fun onSaleRequest() {
          salesEmployees.forEach { it.onSaleRequest() }
       }
       ... //more functions
   }

   private val .... // other Managers

   // also at some point employees are added using this API...
   fun addEmployee(employee: EmployeeActions) {
      employees.add(employee)
   }
   
}
```

**Question**:
Is there a kotlin-y way of writing this code in a scalable way?

In the real case, the client will only call APIs on these `xyzManager` objects and the job of each of them is to simply pass that information down to all employees.

Comment: More context would be required to give you a proper answer. The way I see it, why don't you have a method in the `Vehicle` interface as all vehicles can be started? Why does `carMaster` inherit from `Car`, `carMaster` **IS NOT A** `Car`? The way I see it would be better to have a method for starting the vehicle in the Vehicle interface and the a method in the `Demo` class that takes in a parameter (say KClass) and depending on  the parameter start the corresonding vehicles.

Comment: @KeyserSöze when was the last time you started your bicycle?  I agree it's not clear what the question is, though.

Comment: @AdamMillerchip hmmm .. In that case, the way to go would be to define an interface, say `Startable`, but then it all depends on the scenario and requirements.

Comment: @KeyserSöze I agree with both you guys that the naming in the example is pretty bad. I'll go modify it, but in the meantime, think of this aggregator guy as a representative of a lot of people. So the client only calls methods on this representative, and it's his/her job to let everyone know of what happened.

Comment: @AdamMillerchip Maybe the example kinda made the question look wrong. What I really want is basically a way where the client only publishes/makes API calls to a "manager", and doesn't know who the real subscribers are. This manager guy's responsibility is to delegate the call to all subscribers.